# PostgreSQL: how to use an external python library?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I have found the Python library striprtf, it can be used:

```
from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text
rtf = "some rtf encoded string"
text = rtf_to_text(rtf)
print(text)
```

Is it possible to use this library in plpython3u function in PostgreSQL?

My function is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rtftxt(txt text) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
    from striprtf import rtf_to_text
    retstring = rtf_to_text(text)(txt)
    return retstring
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpython3u';
```

But when run it

```
SELECT rtftxt('Whatever your rtf text goes here')
```

I receive:

```
ERROR:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'striprtf'
CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  PL/Python function "rtftxt", line 2, in <module>
    from striprtf import rtf_to_text
PL/Python function "rtftxt"
SQL state: 38000 (edited)
```

Comment: What happens if you run it?

Comment: Yes you can that is one of the reasons there is the `u(ntrusted)` in `plpython3u`. It just needs to be in the same environment as the Postgres server is running in.

Comment: I have edited the 1st post

Comment: When you run *what* you received that error?  You haven't shown us something that could be run in PostgreSQL.

Comment: My mistake, sorry, Fixed the 1st post

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward, whatever environment you are running the Postgres server in does not have `striprtf` installed for Python 3.

Comment: I did not install any additional Python libs , I use what is installed with PostgreSQL. At least it can be used in AWS RDS. Ok, what should I do?

Comment: I don't understand.  You can't use plpython3u on RDS in the first place, so how did you get the error you report? It should have failed at an earlier step and with a different error.

Comment: Now I am working in local environment. RDS it can be later

Comment: 1) What @jjanes is telling you is that AWS RDS does not allow you to use `plpython3u`, see [RDS Postgres extensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html) 2) In your local environment you need to have `striprtf` installed. This is basic Python.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver please answer & I mark it. I.e. I install the lib on the server where PostgreSQL installed and then I can use it?